# Where could an UnobservedTaskException be occurring?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, async-await

I have a WPF client that accesses a WCF service. The service runs along very nicely using a timer to execute some processing every n minutes. The client UI has a `ProcessNow` command, which overrides the service's timer, and performs the processing immediately. I am trying to sort out a usability problem where clicking the `Process Now` button more than once, while processing is still busy, results in a "connection closed" exception, from the WCF comms channel I assume, followed by a `UnobservedTaskException`.

The exception message explains that its cause is either not waiting on the task, or not accessing its `Exception` property. I only have two apparent uses of a `Task` anywhere in my solution, and one is in my view model:

```
async void ExecuteProcessNowCommand()
{
        await _proxy.ProcessAsync(true);
}
```

The other is in a small utility method in the same viewmodel:

```
private void ExecuteWithTimeout(Action task, int? timeout = null)
{
    timeout = timeout ?? HostServiceConstants.ServiceControlTimeout;
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var timedTask = new Task(task, source.Token);
    timedTask.Start();
    bool done = timedTask.Wait(timeout.Value);
    if (!done)
    {
        source.Cancel();
        var frame = new StackFrame(1);
        var methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
        _logger.Warn("'{0}' timed out after {1} milliseconds.", methodName, timeout);
    }
}
```

In the first code excerpt, I do seem to be waiting on the task, but I am more suspicious of the second, based on an example I found somewhere online. I use that to try and perform non-blocking checks like:

```
bool CanExecuteProcessNowCommand()
{
    bool result = false;
    ExecuteWithTimeout(() =>
        {

            try
            {
                result = _proxy.CanUserForceProcessing();
            }
            catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
            {
                result = false;
            }
        });
    return result;
}
```

The last piece of code is called in my WCF client when I try and keep my command button updated with:

```
ProcessNow.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

I am very new to both async and WCF, so please excuse any obvious blunders here.

Comment: Where are you calling `ExecuteProcessNowCommand()` in your code?

Comment: Add an exception handler around the contents of your first function and catch an `AggregateException`, then put a breakpoint in there and look at the `Exception` or `Exceptions` property to see what is causing the failure.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `ExecuteProcessNowCommand()` is called by WPF when I click the "Process Now" button, which is bound to the command. I don't explicitly call it anywhere.

Comment: @SteveMitcham Aah, thank you. I left the `catch` block out of my excerpt, and I've also left it out of my attention. I was catching only `FaultException`, expected from WCF, which I had given up on when I couldn't get that working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteProcessNowCommand` will not cause this. If an unhandled exception is thrown in async void method, process is taken down. So that's not the case.

Only thing left is `ExecuteWithTimeout`. Yes it can cause result in `UnObservedTaskException` if unhandled exception is thrown in the `timedTask`.

You're waiting on it, waiting should observe the exception, but you're waiting with a Timeout. If the exception is thrown after the Timeout has been passed, you'll see this behavior.

You need to attach continuation to the `timedTask` and observe the exception.

Comment: It isn't actually an `async void`. I don't declare any async method, but the WCF proxy generator does. When I tried throwing a `FaultException`, somewhere I read that async void would take the process down, so I made `Process` return `int`. Now the generated `ProcessAsync` returns `Task<int>`. Gonna look closer at `timedTask` first though. What you say seems to fit that scenario.

Comment: @ProfK I believe when `UnObservedTaskException` is thrown, you could inspect the `InnerException` property to find more info about where the original exception has occured. That should help you